# Asymptotic Analysis question

Tags: inequality, asymptotics

Let $x>0$ be some variable that I am interested in analyzing in the limit $x\to\infty$.
Let $y = x+c$ for some constant $c$.

> Is $\sqrt{y} - \sqrt{x} \geq f(c) > 0$ for some function $f$ of only $c$?

This feels "obvious", but I am having quite a bit of difficulty in establishing it, so perhaps I am just Very Wrong.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{x+c}-\sqrt{x})=0$ so the only $f(c)$ which could work in your bound is $f(c)=0$.